# You are not fit for life here... Is it correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have a question that I want to consult:

I have a boss work in my country.
He is under challenging to get an official position
But after a period of time, I realize that he is not "suit" with this positon.
and I want to talk to him that:

> You should go home, You are not fit for life here

Is this sentence being used in daily life? If not, which sentence should be used here.

Comment: What are you trying to say?  "Fit for life" is a relatively recent English expression, but it does not mean what I think you want it to mean.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Whether or not something is appropriate is dependent on context; please [edit] it to describe the scenario and what you are trying to communicate using other words. In the absence of other context, I would say this statement is very harsh, perhaps more harsh than you intend.

Comment: If I said that to my boss, I would expect to be fired.

Comment: *Life here doesn't suit you* or *This place doesn't suit you* is a nicer way of stating it than *You are not suited for ....*

Comment: I have a boss work in my country?? He is under challenging?? He is not "suit" to the position.

Answer (score 3):

> "You should go home, You are not fit for life here"

As others have been saying in the comments, this statement is too direct and is likely to be taken as an insult. Saying that someone isn't "fit to live" somewhere is like saying they don't deserve to be there (or, worse yet, that they ought to be killed because they don't deserve to live there.) It's the kind of thing an evil villain might say in a movie when making a threat.

You need to soften the language, especially since you are talking to your boss in a professional context. Here is one alternative that would probably be more suitable for you:

> "You should consider going home, this job doesn't seem to be a good match for you"

Here's one that would use the word *fit*:

> "Perhaps you should go home, maybe you aren't the best fit for this job"

Comment: I had a similar answer, I think yours is better. "Good match" and "Best Fit" are very good choices of phrasing I think. I'd also avoid tying the two parts of the sentences together so closely, They're likely best expressed in an extended conversation to provide opportunity to actually converse and gauge whether the conclusion is going to be received well.

Comment: The obvious way to "soften" one's assertion of a "mismatch" like this is to explicitly identify the *circumstances* rather than the *person* (the addressee) as the problematic element. ***Life here doesn't suit you*** rather than anything like ***You are not well suited to life here***.

Comment: @Fumble - Sure, but let's change "Life" to "This job": _This job doesn't suit you_.

Comment: I assumed the boss's problem was more to do with being in a radically different society, climate, or similar. But I suppose that's because I wouldn't normally expect a *native* Anglophone to use *[life] **here*** to mean *in your **job** here*. I guess it could stretch to *your job here in the company we both work for* - but that seems like an incredibly rude thing to say to your boss, whatever the context and whatever the precise words used.

Comment: I have to agree with FumbleFingers that even with softer language, it’s difficult to tell someone that they don’t fit in and should leave the country without being disrespectful if not outright rude. Of course it all depends on context but I’m having a hard time imagining one where it wouldn’t be rude. I think there is a question buried here that might be welcomed on [workplace.se] or [interpersonal.se]

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I focused on this tidbit from the OP: _ I realize that he is not "suit" with this position_. So I've assumed it's less about climate and the surrounding society, and more about job duties and responsibilities. But it's hard to say for sure in a question as vague as this one.

Answer (score 1):

With the verb **suit** it is a two-way street.

> You are not suited for the circus.
>
> The circus is not suited to you.

Depending on what you mean to say, and whether you intend to be gentle or harsh, you might choose the one or the other.

> You are not suited to be a member of the House of Representatives.
>
> The House of Representatives is not suited to you.